# filtering list of dataclass in order to get information

Tags: python, list

I have a dataclass defined as

```
@dataclass
class UserInfo:
    name: str
    salary: int
```

And I am storing list of dataclass

```
userList = [UserInfo(name: 'john', 'salary': 100000), UserInfo(name: 'rick', 'salary': 150000)]
```

Now I want to know salary of john how can I get this information using list in oneliner inside a string.

```
print(f"salary of john is {salary for user in userList if user.name == 'john'}") # somefilter needed for {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```py
userList = [UserInfo(name='john', salary=100000), UserInfo(name='rick', salary=150000)]
salary = [user.salary for user in userList if user.name == 'john'][0]
print(f"salary of john is {salary}")
```

If you are going to use  this way of searching the list by names more frequently, I would override the `__eq__` method of the dataclass

```py
@dataclass
class UserInfo:
    name: str
    salary: int
    def  __eq__(self, other):
        if other == self.name:
            return True
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":                       
    userList = [UserInfo(name='john', salary=100000), UserInfo(name='rick', salary=150000)]
    idx = userList.index('john')
    print(f"salary of john is {userList[idx].salary}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following

```
next(user.salary for user in userList if user.name == 'john')
```

In this case, python stops to iterate over the elements if we have found something.